# Run i3 (4.12) inside of Gnome (3.20.3)

Tags: linux, gnome, window-manager, desktop-environments, i3-window-manager

I run Linux Manjaro and I really love the way Gnome 3 looks, but I hate having to manually move windows out of the way of each other. I tried `i3` and really liked it, however it looks pretty hideous.

My plan was to replace Gnome 3 window manager (metacity I think) with i3. I have tried a variety of guides and all result in one outcome: i3 starts but there is no sign of Gnome running at all (at least, not visually)

When I try to run `gnome-tweak-tool`, I notice the extensions menu is missing and this has been output to console:

`WARNING : Shell not installed or running
WARNING : Error detecting shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 275, in __init__
    raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
WARNING : Shell not running`

If they are important, this is my current configuration:

`/usr/share/xsessions/gnome-i3.desktop`:

`[Desktop Entry]
Name=GNOME with i3
Comment=A GNOME session using i3 as the window manager.
TryExec=gnome-session
Exec=gnome-session --session=i3
Type=Application`

`/usr/share/gnome-session/sessions/i3.session`:

`[GNOME Session]
Name=i3
RequiredComponents=gnome-settings-daemon;gnome-panel;i3`

Pardon my ignorance, I am *very* new to Linux as a whole.

Can someone help me get i3 to run inside of Gnome on Manjaro? (I do select Gnome with i3 at the login screen)

Comment: You can try to add `DesktopNames=GNOME-Flashback;GNOME` to `gnome-i3.destkop`. Without it gnome-panel will not start.

Answer (score 1):

i3 is not a window manager. i3 is a complete X11 server client, so you can not just criss-cross GNOME and i3.

Imagine i3 as a small GNOME.

Try something such as [gTile](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/28/gtile/).

Comment: Oh, really. I don't know how I didn't see that earlier. If that's true, how do the guides that claim to run i3 inside of gnome get good responses? (edit: I will look into the gTile extension, thank you!)

Comment: @Harry they aren't actually running i3 inside of Gnome, they are running components of the gnome-system alongside i3 using dbus signals and session setup tricks. The difference between a WM (window manager) and a DE (display environment) are subtle, but basically i3 is a WM that only handles where/how the windows get displayed, it knows nothing about the rest of the system, Gnome on the other hand is a DE that uses dbus to keep track of the state of EVERYTHING (that it knows about).